# Technical term for Cisco's VSS

Tags: terminology, vss

What's the technical term for *Virtual Switching System* (VSS) by Cisco Systems?

In [this](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-6500-virtual-switching-system-1440/prod_qas0900aecd806ed74b.html) Q&A, Cisco calls it a *network system virtualization technology*. Since I couldn't find another vendor using the same term, I'm uncertain.

Comment: The key difference between VSS and other network system virtualization technologies is the peering of supervisor modules that each manage a chassis containing one or many switching modules. It is a virtual switch stack of two chassis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Virtual Switching System**

That's the term.

If you are looking for another vendor that does virtual switch stacks where you connect the switches together with single mode fiber like the VSS Supervisor engine you would search for the term  **virtual switch** or **virtual switch stack**
Adding the stack into your search will help you to NOT get a bunch of virtual switching hits related to something like VMwares virtual distributed switch.

What VSS feature are you looking for?  If you have VSS capability on a Catalyst switch there are a lot of features available.

**Possible Terms**

- Virtual Switch Stack
- Virtual Switching
- Virtual Switch
- Consolidated Switch Stack (A minority of vendors used this in their nomenclature)

Comment: _What VSS feature are you looking for?_ I'm not looking for a specific feature. I would like to search for solutions. I'm looking for a term that does for me what _first-hop redundancy protocol_ (FHRP) does for someone reading about HSRP.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for an HA solution.  Lookup high availability.

Comment: I didn't articulate myself well enough. FHRP is a term for protocols managing redundant routers. For example, if someone is reading about HSRP and wants to know more about alternatives, then searching for _first-hop redundancy protocols_ will help.

Comment: HA is high availability.  ie, redundancy.  I understand what FHRP is as well HSRP.  I implement everyday.  You were talking about VSS for virtual switching now your are talking about FHRP.  I think you need to ask a question about implementing redundancy rather than trying to button hole yourself into a particular protocol.

Comment: I'm not talking about protocols. I'm talking about a word useful for looking up a set of protocols/solutions.

Comment: You are the one that keeps throwing protocols that have features bound to them.  If you clearly state your uses case and what you want to do then words can be given to you that reflect your need.

Comment: I think your answer get's it right because it helps to get rid of unrelated search results. However, so far I coulnd't find another vendor speaking of _virtual switching system_. Maybe there isn't competition in the field of peering whole chassis.

Comment: A non-vendor specific hardware term would be *virtual switch stack*  This where you connect your switches via a backplane cable of some sort and managed the physical switches that are connected together via a single CLI or web interface.  It makes the stack look like a single physical switch.